# Rails map unique values and order in same statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following statement identifies all the unique items

```
@products = @volumes.map(&:product).uniq
```

However, in view of further processing, the goal is to order the items as well.  The following type of statement will not process because `undefined method 'order' for #<Array:`

```
@products = @volumes.map(&:product).order("max_units DESC").uniq
```

How can this be accomplished succinctly?

Comment: What is @volumnes, how does volumnes and products relate? Because the question if you want to use pure ruby methods or activerecord database oriented methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@volumes is an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. When you use `map`, it'll return a Ruby array which doesn't implement the `order` method

Comment: so how could this be ordered properly then?  A subsequent command leads to the same array handling...

Comment: I assume you have a relationship between `Product` and `Volume` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Product.where(id: @volumes.map(&:id)).order("max_units DESC")
```